# Is there a way to separate a Go executable to several files?

Tags: go

I am shipping several executables compiled with Go. Each executable by itself doesn't contain a lot of code but each of them uses a common library that includes logging, configuration management, a communication layer, etc...

This leads to each executable being between 15-20mb sometimes for as little as 1000 own lines of code.

Is there a way in Go (currently available or planned for a future release) that will allow separating the application into several files (i.e. dlls in Windows, .so Linux/Mac)?

I know I can compile the library and then use it as external binary but then I will not get the benefits of the type system and the Go compiler optimization. Am I wrong here and there is a way to do it?

Comment: If size really is a problem try stripping the binaries from its debug information.

Comment: 15-20MB is trivially small in pretty much any situation except embedded systems. Are you sure you have a problem to solve here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer: *Kind of?*

It sounds like what you're trying to accomplish is a shared library.

The Go compiler has been able to produce shared libraries since 1.5 with the `-buildmode=c-shared` build flag:

```
go build -o helloworld.so -buildmode=c-shared
```

And, as of [Go 1.10](https://golang.org/doc/go1.10#compiler), the functionality is additionally supported on Windows

So, compiling to DLL is also a one-liner:

```
go build -o helloworld.dll -buildmode=c-shared
```

The problem that you're going to run into is actually *using* those libraries, especially in a cross operating system way:

In *nix, you can use CGO to accomplish this:

```
package example

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -lfoo
//
// #include <foo.h>
import "C"

func main() {
    C.bar()
}
```

Windows gets its own [Wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/WindowsDLLs) (who's surprised?).

I'll leave you with a few thoughts on this:

1. There's *nothing* wrong with a 15-20mb binary (although, you should try [upx](https://upx.github.io/) to shave off some of that fat because why not?), you should be concerned when you're pushing 10s of 100s of gigs. Space is cheap these days.
2. Writing something that can be compiled into a single binary, regardless of OS, is one of the best perks of Go.
3. `CGO_ENABLED=0` saves you a ton of space from your binaries. Keeping it enabled (which you need to use these features), isn't doing you any favors.
4. You're right to assume that since the compiler can't optimize for included libraries, that ultimately you're not going to save much, if any space, in small use cases.

My last point, then I'll stop preaching at you: Focus on writing code. Binary size should not be your concern unless you're trying to fit on embedded devices.

Good luck friend.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. I am aware of "-buildmode=c-shared" I just hoped there is a native Go way of doing it... Like in any other language :). I understand what you said about the binary size not being important but our product is already 3Gb installation size and if I am shipping 150mb instead of 30 I have to justify it somehow. I will try the other things you mentioned to reduce the size as much as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a "native go way" beyond what I've already said? Go won't magically compile a bunch of shared libraries from a single `main` function, if that's what you're asking. Go does exactly what you tell it to do. If you want it to build multiple outputs, you have to separate your code into multiple `go build`able chunks.

Comment: I mean that it will generate something which can be then imported using the import clause the same way as you are importing something via "using" in C#. Can I tell it to build a particular package into a different file and then the executable will find that file during run?

Comment: I know of nothing like that, that exists in Go. Again, Go doesn't perform magic. You need to be explicit about what you import, and what you `go build` - It's perhaps one of the larger hurdles people have switching to Go from other languages, is things you took for granted require a bit more work. -- Not to get preachy again, but I think you need to look at the problem of WHY your binaries are 3Gb+ if they're that large. That's not an unreasonable file size for something of large complexity, but Docker, kubectl, terraform, helm, and other large projects aren't even close to that.

Comment: Each binary is not so large (20-30mb) but the entire product is large and we are working to see if this can be reduced.

Answer (score 2):

Are the things you are shipping closely related to each other? If so, it might make more sense to combine them into a single executable that takes commands on the command line to decide which "executable" to start executing.

So instead of shipping 'cmd1' and 'cmd2' and 'cmd3', you just ship one program that can be invoked this way

```
$ prog cmd1

$ prog cmd2

$ prog cmd3
```

You have to do a bit of extra work to parse the first argument and decide which sub-command to launch.